# Flow between Chat and SE is confusing

Tags: discussion, design, chat, user-interface

Clicking on "chat" from the StackExchange dropdown menu (top left corner) loads the chat flow within the page.

[image: screenshot]

Clicking on "ux.stackexchange.com" in the chat room in the paragraph on the top right opens the page in a new window.

[image: screenshot]

Can this be made consistent in some way? Should it be a new window all the time?

Also, not sure if this deserves a new Question posting but as it's related:

The flow isn't smooth between the ux.se site to the All Rooms chat to the chat Room itself. The interface jolts and header nav completely changes.

Shouldn't this be consistent in some way? My first time through was very disorienting and I didn't know if I was still on the site or not.

Comment: Chat just opens all links in a new window because it's a webapp, main site doesn't because it's not a webapp. Chat's always been sort of an oddity, useful as it is. Agreed that the All Rooms page is a bit weird though, sort of a third design